# Spin up docker-compose file on host from Jenkins running in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, devops, host

I'd like to spin up 2 containers (front-end & backend) described in a docker-compose.dev.yml file located on my Ubuntu server from within Jenkins. Jenkins is running inside a docker container on the same server. How would I go about this?